# On SN65HVD1780 are external pullup and pulldowns

Tags: pullup, pulldown, transceiver

On transceiver SN65HVD1780 are external pullup and pulldowns required on A,B,DE,RE,D,R lines? The datasheet mentions that the part has internal pullups and pulldowns but it's not clear if external pullups or pulldowns are required.

Answer (score 0):

Not needed to pull the lines. But resistors on A/B fall under the umbrella of RS485 terminations and may be required depending on your setup. They aren't used to "pull" the lines so much as to bias them along with with other resistors.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, since the SN65HVD1780 is an RS485 transceiver and [RS485 requires](https://www.windmill.co.uk/rs485.html) matching resistors to match the impedance of the cable (could be 100 or 120Ω). If you're not building an RS485 bus then you can drive whatever you want with it.

Here is a description of the lines:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked a page in the datasheet, page 22. That answers my question.

Yes. External pullups and pulldowns are recommended for best performance!

Comment: Those pulldowns are required to force the transceiver in receive mode while the microcontroller is still in reset and does not drive its GPIOs. What the datasheet actually talks about is the *value* of these resistors (larger resistors would generate larger voltages if they pick up noise).